# Can't find Java folder in Program Files

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I hate asking this, but I've never been able to find my Java folder on my current PC. I'd like to find it so I could use a keystore command to find my SHA and just to know where it is. I found a SHA number through gradlewindow/signing report, but now the api page isn't accepting it so I wanted to check through a 'keystore' command, which you apparently have to call with the command line folder path set somewhere in the Java folder. Here are both my program files. I've been successfully developing and publishing my android game for a year on this PC, so I figured I must have a Java folder somewhere. The toolbar search box hasn't helped (it never does), it just gives me website suggestions through Bing.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android Studio and Android do not use a java from Oracle or Sun but use OpenJDK that is an open sourced java instead, so there won't be a java folder under Program Files if you didn't installed java for other uses. Android Studio's java can be found in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre.

Comment: Is there a quick way to set the command line folder path to the .../androidstudio_32/android studio/jre/jre/bin folder, the entire path is pretty deep. Someone mentioned a keyboard shortcut in another post.

Comment: Just create a symlink. On Windows use command mklink, on Linux use ln. It works like s shortcut but it's on system level.

Comment: I knew I'd be down voted for this one but I'm keeping it up just so I can accept your answer. Now that I know what the issue was, it's obvious there was no Java folder in the first place, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Go to Start -> Control Panel -> Java -> View

In the 'Path' column you can get the location.

Someone has already posted it here: https://superuser.com/questions/1148677/finding-location-java-home-in-windows-10/1148743 , please refer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the path on my Win 10 machine: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_162.

Comment: That's where it is for most everyone apparently, but as you can see from my screenshots I don't have it there.

Comment: You're looking at Program Files (x86), which is where 32-bit apps are installed by default.

Comment: There are 2 screenshots in the question, 1 from Program Files (x86) and another from just Program Files.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the JDK first you should press on that JDK icon after its downloaded and run it. While it's running it will ask where you want that file to be downloaded and by default, it will download to your C:/ drive.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to install java [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/)